# Why i cant get access to minio console from docker container?

Tags: docker, amazon-s3, docker-compose, minio

I want to create one docker container with minio and also create one bucket at once.When I try to go to the console (localhost:9001) I get an error. Whats wrong with my `docker-compose` ?

`docker-compose.yaml` :

```
version: '3'
services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    container_name: minio
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    volumes:
      - "./data:/data"
      - "./config:/root/.minio"
    environment:
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio-access-key
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio-secret-key
    command: server /data && server /minio-image/storage --console-address :9001
    networks:
      - minio-network
    restart: always
  create-bucket:
    image: minio/mc:latest
    container_name: create-post-bucket
    environment:
      MINIO_HOST: minio
      MINIO_ACCESS_KEY: minio-access-key
      MINIO_SECRET_KEY: minio-secret-key
    entrypoint: ["sh", "-c"]
    command: "mc mb local/post-bucket || true"
    depends_on:
      - minio
    networks:
      - minio-network
networks:
  minio-network:
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several issues in your `docker-compose.yaml`.

### Deprecated configuration

When starting up the `minio` container, the very first output is:

```
minio            | WARNING: MINIO_ACCESS_KEY and MINIO_SECRET_KEY are deprecated.
minio            |          Please use MINIO_ROOT_USER and MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD
```

So we should fix that.

### Invalid command for minio container

Next, your `command` seems problematic. You're running:

```
server /data && server /minio-image/storage --console-address :9001
```

But that entire command line gets passed as arguments to the `minio` command, which doesn't make any sense. You probably want:

```
command: server /data/ --console-address :9001
```

### Invalid configuration for create-bucket container

The `create-bucket` container attempts to run `mc mb local/post-bucket`, but the `local` alias is invalid:

```
[root@e874a3d8e8c8 /]# mc alias list local
local
  URL       : http://localhost:9000
  AccessKey :
  SecretKey :
  API       :
  Path      : auto
```

The minio service isn't running on `localhost`. The `MINIO_HOST` environment variable isn't used by the minio client. According to [this documentation](https://github.com/minio/mc/blob/master/docs/minio-client-complete-guide.md#specify-temporary-host-configuration-through-environment-variable), you can provide a configuration in the `MC_HOST_<hostname>` environment variable.

Additionally, the way your `create-bucket` container is configured, it may start up and run *before* minio is ready to service requests, causing it to fail.

### Bind mounts instead of docker volumes

Using a bind mount (`./data:/data`) instead of named volume is often sub-optimal because it leads to uid/gid conflicts between the host and container. Unless you *really* need to share the contents of that directory between the host and container, you're better off using a named volumethe contents of that directory between the host and container, you're better off using a named volume.

---

We can fix all of these issues  with the following `docker-compose.yaml`:

```
services:
  minio:
    image: minio/minio:latest
    ports:
      - 9000:9000
      - 9001:9001
    volumes:
      - minio-data:/data
    environment:
      MINIO_ROOT_USER: $MINIO_ROOT_USER
      MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD: $MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD
    command: server /data --console-address :9001
    restart: unless-stopped

  create-bucket:
    image: minio/mc:latest
    environment:
      MC_HOST_minio: http://${MINIO_ROOT_USER}:${MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD}@minio:9000
    entrypoint:
      - sh
      - -c
      - |
        until mc ls minio > /dev/null 2>&1; do
          sleep 0.5
        done

        mc mb minio/post-bucket

volumes:
  minio-data:
```

This assumes that you're setting `MINIO_ROOT_USER` and `MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD` in your `.env` file, like this:

```
MINIO_ROOT_USER=admin
MINIO_ROOT_PASSWORD=minio-secret-key
```

The `entrypoint` script in the `create-bucket` container loops until `minio` is ready to service requests; then it creates the bucket.

Running `docker-compose up` with this configuration results in:

```
Creating network "container_default" with the default driver
Creating volume "container_minio-data" with default driver
Creating container_minio_1  ... done
Creating create-post-bucket ... done
Attaching to container_minio_1, create-post-bucket
minio_1          | Formatting 1st pool, 1 set(s), 1 drives per set.
minio_1          | WARNING: Host local has more than 0 drives of set. A host failure will result in data becoming unavailable.
minio_1          | MinIO Object Storage Server
minio_1          | Copyright: 2015-2023 MinIO, Inc.
minio_1          | License: GNU AGPLv3 <https://www.gnu.org/licenses/agpl-3.0.html>
minio_1          | Version: RELEASE.2023-06-02T23-17-26Z (go1.19.9 linux/amd64)
minio_1          |
minio_1          | Status:         1 Online, 0 Offline.
minio_1          | S3-API: http://192.168.192.2:9000  http://127.0.0.1:9000
minio_1          | Console: http://192.168.192.2:9001 http://127.0.0.1:9001
minio_1          |
minio_1          | Documentation: https://min.io/docs/minio/linux/index.html
minio_1          | Warning: The standard parity is set to 0. This can lead to data loss.
create-post-bucket | Bucket created successfully `minio/post-bucket`.
create-post-bucket exited with code 0
```

At this point, I can access the minio console as expected at http://localhost:9001 on my docker host.